# I want to use AND grep operation, but i don't know how

Tags: regex, bash, shell, unix, grep

There are one program named pro1 and one data file named file1 in the folder.

In data file,

```
Alex|New york karlos|011-1234-5678
Karl|Chicago koroq|012-3456-7890
Richard|New york ntown|023-4567-8990
```

And I'd like to use grep AND.

I write down this code, but it didn't work

```
for arg in $@; do
if[ count -eq 1]
then
  egrep -i $arg file1 | $temp
else
  egrep -i $arg $temp | $temp
fi
done
```

echo $temp

When I enter "./pro1 Alex New york"
I want to print Alex|New york karlos|011-1234-5678

How can i do it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File 'mgrep':

```
#!/bin/bash

TEMP=/tmp/mgrep-$$
touch $TEMP

COUNTER=0
for arg in $@; do
   let COUNTER=COUNTER+1
   if [ $COUNTER -eq 1 ]; then
      grep -i "$arg" > $TEMP
   else
      TEMP2=/tmp/mgrep-$$-$COUNTER
      grep -i "$arg" $TEMP > $TEMP2
      rm $TEMP
      TEMP=$TEMP2
   fi
done
cat $TEMP
rm $TEMP
```

Run it like this:

```
cat file1 | mgrep one two three
```